# Feature engineering based off of a variable length vector

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, feature-engineering

I am studying a particular type of system. I have a theory that allows me to simulate how the system evolves based on some initial conditions. Now, looking at a real object, I am using machine learning to determine what initial conditions, if simulated, would give rise to an object with those properties.

I am running into a difficulty when trying to engineer a feature and would like some ideas for resolving it. The problem is that at certain stages of the system's life, a vector of variable length $\vec x$ may arise. For most of the system's life, the vector is empty. Then, it may have one number, two numbers, three numbers, and so on. Each of these numbers only has a certain probability of being observed in practice, with some numbers being more likely to be observed than others.

I also know that the numbers closest to $x_\text{mid}$ are most likely to be observed, where $x_\text{mid}$ is a value that I can simulate and is also observable.

In general, the simulation will always have a longer $\vec x$ than an object being observed, because some of the values in $\vec x$ have very low probability of being observed.

I want to engineer one or more features based off of $\vec x$. If the object I observe has no $x$'s, no problem, I won't predict based on the feature made out of $\vec x$. But I am at a loss as to what to do when there are $\vec x$s. Any advice?